# mysql error 2003 (hy000) cant connect to MYSQl server on localhost

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2003

I am trying to connect to mysql and keep getting this error:

> mysql error 2003 (hy000) cant connect to MYSQl server on localhost (10061)

I tried typing in: sc query mysql to command prompt command line and got:

```
SERVICE_NAME: mysql
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 1077  (0x435)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL service is not running. Type `sc start mysql` to start it.

Comment: thank you for your response, i started the sql but it is still not working the error i am now getting is: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'rashi'@'localhost' (using password: YES                                        thank you

Comment: Is the username and password set correctly in the mysql_connect() command?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

1. Go to Start -> Services.msc -> start mysql service (name could be MYSQL57)
2. Go to your bin folder in MySQL directory (eg C:\Program Files\MySQL 5.7\bin) -> right click on mysqld.exe -> Run as Administrator
3. Open cmd in your bin folder in MySQL directory -> execute this command 'mysql -u root -p
   -> Enter the password

And you are done!!!